# How to approach code review with limited resources

Tags: code-reviews, tools

I've been given the following task:

> A company is giving source code for its product (comprising over 1
>   million lines of C++, Java, with some assembly) for my review.  The
>   code will be loaded onto a Windows machine that I do not control, has
>   no USB ports, no network, and is a small controlled room.  I must
>   somehow sift through the code, figure out where the implementation of
>   Action X is, and then trace through the code to see how Action X ties
>   into the rest of the product.

The last time I did this, they gave me the code along with Notepad.  Since I couldn't add software, that was it.  I found myself using DOS command shells to get a grep-like ability with `FINDSTR /R` but this was painful, as you might imagine. I think I have a chance to tell them what I would like installed on the machine next time.

My question: how might one approach this chore in a logical and efficient manner?  If you were given this task, how would you approach it?

Comment: In the 80's we often only had grep and text editors for code reviews. Often there was not even a symbolic debugger either. It is possible to do a lot with grep if you know the regular expression syntax.

Comment: Of course in the 80s people didn't drop 90GB of code in your lap and ask you to understand it. :)

Comment: @Fixee 90GB of code is not comprehensible in any detail.